# how to search similar strings in SQLite

Tags: android, string, sqlite, search

I want to search table "TABLE_TOURS" for similar words of "query" in cloumn "COLUMN_TITLE" and return a list "List".
helps me plzz

```
public List<Tour> getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
    String selection =  ToursDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_TITLE + " MATCH ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};
    return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
}
public List<Tour> query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "getwordsmatches result"+ selection +" "+ selectionArgs);
    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(ToursDBOpenHelper.TABLE_TOURS);

    Cursor cursor = builder.query(dbhelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "cursor of db result "+ cursor);
    List<Tour> tours = cursorToList(cursor);
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "tours are "+ tours);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
    return tours;
}
```

and its cursorToList method:

```
private List<Tour> cursorToList(Cursor cursor) {
    List<Tour> tours = new ArrayList<Tour>();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Tour tour = new Tour();
            tour.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(ToursDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID)));
            tour.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ToursDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_TITLE)));
            tour.setCate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ToursDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_CATE)));
            tour.setDetail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ToursDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_DETAIL)));
            tour.setDescription(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ToursDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_DESC)));
            tour.setImage(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ToursDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_IMAGE)));
            tours.add(tour);
        }
    }
    return tours;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "similar words"?

Comment: for example user type "dog" in search bar and see a list of "dog","dogs","dogs are"

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SQL LIKE statement for this. In SQL, the % character represents any string of 0 or more characters. So, for example, you could write

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%dog%'
```

This will match any string containing "dog", such as "dog", "dogs", "I like dogs", and "123dog321".

Your exact arguments will vary based on the structure of your table, but this is the gist of it.

Comment: I think problem is in List<Tour> tours = cursorToList(cursor); can u help me with that?

Comment: Post your code for that method and I'll see what I can do. Also, update your code if you successfully made the LIKE statement work.

Comment: I tried that before. log shows that problem is when List wanna create from cursor.

Comment: Post your updated code please, including the method you believe isn't working.

Comment: You still aren't showing me the relevant code; if you think the problem is with ` cursorToList(...)`, please post the code for that method.

Comment: That code looks good to me. What is your problem now? What isn't working as expected?

Comment: problem is app stop working when it wanna do List<Tour> tours = cursorToList(cursor);

Comment: I can't tell you what the problem is if you don't post the LogCat error

Answer (score 2):

try using the Like keyword it would match any syntax you specify [See this tutorial here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm)

[and Sqlite Webpage](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#like)

---

---

Example : `Cursor c = myDB.query(MY_DATABASE_TABLE, "songname","songname like ?" , new String[]{"%"+MATCH_STRING+"%"}, null,"SongHit", null);`

Comment: if it solved your problem please flag it for others to get benefit

Comment: I think problem is in List<Tour> tours = cursorToList(cursor);
can u help me with that?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing please post the log cat error so that I could help you

Answer (score 1):

Your method that executes the query should be like this:

```
public List<Tour> findByTitle(String string) {

        String query;
        query = "SELECT * FROM tours WHERE title LIKE '%"+ string +"%'";
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Returned " + cursor.getCount() + " rows");
        List<Tour> tours = cursorToList(cursor);
        return tours;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would not work, as the statement after LIKE would need wildcards to work properly.

Comment: @NathanWalters I'm using this very code myself. And it does work.

Comment: Yes, because you just edited it! Now it will work.

Comment: @NathanWalters if you don't put % around the string, it works just fine but only returns item with that exact title. I edited it to suit this question.

Comment: That's why I told you it wouldn't work, your answer didn't suit the question. This, however, does work, so you're good.