# Searching a date with parameter 'LIKE'

Tags: python, sqlite

I am building a small program in Python and SQlite where a client can type a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD and get back all the plays that take place in that specific date. All the plays are store in Play.db which saves the date as: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM

I do not want the user to type the exact date with hour and minutes. He just has to type the year-month-day and all the plays in that specific date should appear.

I realise that I need the keyword 'LIKE' and pass my variable between '%'variable'%' in order to get a similar (not exact) match.
However I am not sure how to do so by using the syntax of my SQLite query:

```
    user_input = input("Please, type the date of the play in format: 'YYYY-MM-DD':")
    search_date = """SELECT * FROM play WHERE play_date LIKE ? """
    cursor.execute(search_date, [(user_input)])
    results = cursor.fetchall()
```

The issue is that 'results' is not populated because the SQL query is looking for exact match.

THEREFORE I tried with %user_input% or %?% but, obsiously, the variable '%user_input%' or %?% is not defined.

I understand how logically is should be done:

[how to search similar strings in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978711/how-to-search-similar-strings-in-sqlite)

But I am not sure how the "LIKE '%'variable'%'" can be obtained using my code syntax.

Comment: Why are you trying to look in the *title* of the play for a *performance date*?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I wroye it by mistake. Now, I fixed it in the original post.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. You should be able to do something like `SELECT ... WHERE date(play_date) = ?`

Comment: *" saves the date as: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`"*: [Edit] your Question and show the `CREATE ...` statement.

Comment: Thanks. I have still an issue though. If a play's starting time is saved in the Play.db at: 2046-08-14 19:30, and the user looks for 2046-08-14, the results is empty. I think because I am looking for an exact match rather than a similar math (%variable%).  how can I look for a partial match using the .execute(input, [variable]) syntax?

Comment: If the user input is in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and the times in the `play_date` column are in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` format (or any other that [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) understand) that snippet will work.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you!

Comment: One possibility: Does that `input()` function leave a newline at the end of the string it returns? `YYYY-MM-DD\n` would of course fail to compare equal to the strings returned by `date()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
user_input = datetime.datetime(input("Please, type the date of the play in format: 'YYYY-MM-DD':"), '%Y-%m-%d')
# 2011-11-11
search_date = f'SELECT * FROM play WHERE play_date LIKE {user_input}'
print(search_date)
# SELECT * FROM play WHERE play_date LIKE 2011-11-11
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Edited to prevent sql injections

Comment: Don't put untrusted user input directly into a SQL statement. That's what parameters are for.

Comment: @Shawn you're right. I was trying to discern what FBSO asked. converting user_input to `datetime.strptime(DATE, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` would be better

Answer (score 1):

Use the `date` function in your query to just compare the dates of your stored datetime values and user input.

```
SELECT * FROM play WHERE date(play_date) = date(?)
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I have one small question more. If I run it, now i get the error 'sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error'. I am not sure why.

Comment: Wildcards, `%` are not needed. Simple parameterized the user input.

Comment: Ok, I thought that % were necessary with the LIKE keyword.
If I run 'SELECT * FROM play WHERE date(play_date) = date(user_input)', I get the error 'no such column: user_input'. I am confused, why is it checking if Play.db has a user_input column? Isn't it an input?.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The wildcards are not needed, just use the `?` placeholder and it should work ;) - I've corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a date function. Also you can use slicing for the string. Like:

```
theDate = input() #example: 2018-12-24
Year = theDate[:3]
Month = theDate[5:6]
Day = theDate[8:9]
```

Answer (score -1):

Good day,
Well it may not be exactly what you want but I would share you some pieces of code I wrote when I wanted to build something like this but this time using Flask and SQLAlchemy.

First is to convert the data to a date/datetime to ensure the data is valid

```
converted_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(user_input, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

Converted to regular SQL query should be

```
SELECT * FROM play WHERE play_date LIKE {"%" + converted_date}
```

Please note that the `"%"` is very important, and putting it at the beginning means you want to search for any date that starts with the inputted date.